# ¿Crear imagen con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

estoy creando un sistema tipo captcha con javascript, he creado el codigo para hacer un codigo aleatorio, y ahora lo que quiero hacer es mostrar ese codigo como una imagen, he buscado en google pero no encuentro nada, espero que me puedan ayudar, les dejo el codigo de lo que llevo.

### index.php

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
   <title>Generar password</title>
   <script src="Sequre/Sequre-1.1.js" language="Javascript" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
</head>
<body onload="generateCode()">
    <form method="post" class="txtTexto2">
        <div id="Sequre"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### sequre.js

```
function generateCode() {
var strCaracteresPermitidos = 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,m,n,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9';
var strArrayCaracteres = new Array(34);
var lon = 6;
strArrayCaracteres = strCaracteresPermitidos.split(',');
var length = lon, i = 0, j, tmpstr = "";
do {
    var randscript = -1
    while (randscript < 1 || randscript > strArrayCaracteres.length || isNaN(randscript)) {
        randscript = parseInt(Math.random() * strArrayCaracteres.length)
    }
    j = randscript;
    tmpstr = tmpstr + strArrayCaracteres[j];
    i = i + 1;
} while (i < length)
document.getElementById('Sequre').innerHTML = tmpstr + '<button onclick="generateCode">Actualizar</button><br><input type="text" name="inputCode" onKeyUp="checkCode">';

}
```

Comment: Pero... para que el captcha sea aprobado hay que comparar el texto de la imagen con un texto de referencia. Dónde almacenarías ese texto para que un bot no lo encontrara?

Comment: lo voy a guardar del lado del servidor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo único que se me ocurre es que puedas utilizar un `Canvas` oculto y convertirlo a imagen usando `toDataURL`:

```js
var ctxCanvas = document.getElementById('canvasOculto').getContext('2d'),
    imagen = document.getElementById('image');


var cadena = "HOLA CARACOLA";

ctxCanvas.canvas.width = ctxCanvas.measureText(cadena).width;
ctxCanvas.fillText(cadena, 0, 10);
imagen.src = ctxCanvas.canvas.toDataURL();
```

```css
canvas{
    border: 1px white dotted;
}
#canvasOculto{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvasOculto' height=15></canvas>
<img id='image'>
<br>
```

---